# How do I work out container widths of section in responsive build if main container is 100% width?

Tags: css, mobile

Im trying to build a mobile first page, usually I work out my container `widths` based on the overall container `max-width`.

So if my container should be `200px wide` and my overall container has `max-width 1000px` then my percentage calculation is 200/1000*100. But how do I make this calculation if my overall container has no `max-width` but instead is set to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance if this is a lame answer but I'd look into an existing the Grid framework, such as http://foundation.zurb.com/ (or other) and build on top of that, rather than writing it from scratch.